# Android: Long-press stops the event chain in SurfaceView implementing OnGestureListener

Tags: android, surfaceview

I am working on an open source Android library to implement a modern-looking menu that relies heavily on gestures: http://omtinez.github.io/ohmenu/

I was able to successfully implement all the functionality that I wanted but when a user performs a long-press, the chain of touch events breaks and the rest of the listeners don't get any touch events until the user lifts the finger and touches the screen again. In other words, none of the listeners receives any touch events after a long press. Is there any way to disable the long-press listener in OnGestureListener? Alternatively, is there a way to re-send the touch event so the rest of the listeners can consume it after the long-press?

Here is the class that takes care of it all: https://github.com/omtinez/ohmenu/blob/master/src/com/omtinez/ohmenu/OhmenuView.java

Thank you,
Oscar

Comment: So when a long click is detected you want to ignore it. Other than that do you want to do anything else? Do you want to do something when the user lifts their finger?

Comment: onUp is still being fired, but I can't really explain why that one is and onScroll isn't. The library needs to be able to handle onUp in all cases to function, it is a fundamental part of the pipeline

Comment: onScroll is triggered only after your finger moves a few pixels, if someone puts a finger down and does not move it onScroll will not figure and long-press will. What you need to do is implement your own `GestureDetector` and then consume the long click using it. I wrote a tutorial on [how to handle a lot of gestures in Android](https://github.com/atgheb/android-gestures-tutorial) a month or so back , look at project 03 for an example. The rest you'll have to do, I can't tell you without looking at your code.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm doing. I am also overriding the long click event like in your tutorial, you can see it [here](https://github.com/omtinez/ohmenu/blob/master/src/com/omtinez/ohmenu/OhmenuView.java), but the events cease after that

Comment: As far as I can tell you are not implementing `GestureDetector` you're just using the one provide. The idea is that in GestureDetector.onTouchEvent` you can call your `GestureListener.onTouchEvent` and have that return `true` or `false` to indicate whether the event was consumed or not. In `GestureListener.onTouchEvent` if a fingure down is detectect `postDelay` a single tap, if the single tap event fires and the finger is still down ignore it / re-set it.

Comment: If move is detected and fingure is down, cancel the single tap event and let scroll execute. If you consume the events, the default action will not take place, so finger down will not result in a long-press because you consume the event. For this you have to implement `GestureDetector` yourself and figure out all the other gestures yourself as well. In my example, if the listener handled the event, the gesture detector did nothing or else it took the default action. In your case you want to take the default action except when you realize that a long-click is taking place.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. If I understood you correctly, not consuming the event would prevent if from getting "caught" by the onLongPress event handler, however, I changed the code to make sure that only MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE was being consumed and return false otherwise in my onTouchEvent handler but the long press is still swallowing the touch events. Did I misunderstand what you explained about the pipeline?

Comment: Sounds about right. However take a look at the `GestureDetector` api. There is a [`setLongpressEnabled`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html#setIsLongpressEnabled(boolean)) method. If you set this to false, it should also have the same effect. Let me know if this works for you and I'll post it as the answer.

Comment: From the doc about setLongPressEnabled: "If it's disabled the user can press and hold down and then later moved their finger and you will get scroll events." That was exactly what I was looking for, flipping that flag did the trick. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [`setLongpressEnabled`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html#setIsLongpressEnabled%28boolean%29) method. If you set this to false, it should disable long press.